File header is not being processed by awk in bash loop
I have a csv file with header, that is expected to have 14 fields.
My gawk script checks the file and writes good and bad lines to 2 separate files. 
However, the header line is not output to either file. It's the only missing line.
while read -r line; 
do
   gawk -k '{if (NF==14) print $0 > "good_file.csv";     \
             else print "["NR"]", "["NF"]", $0 > "bad_file.csv"}';
done < hd.csv

csv input file sample: hd.csv
test_id,vehicle_id,test_date,test_class_id,test_type,test_result,test_mileage,postcode_area,make,model,colour,fuel_type,cylinder_capacity,first_use_date
1645480751,1374211238,2016-01-01,4,NT,P,117033,SM,VOLKSWAGEN,POLO,BLACK,PE,1600,2000-06-23
1393462389,1153769898,2016-01-01,4,NT,P,99292,NE,VOLKSWAGEN,PASSAT,BLUE,DI,1968,2006-11-30
1863202023,1485039300,2016-01-01,7,NT,PRS,170320,E,MERCEDES,SPRINTER 313 CDI LWB,WHITE,DI,2148,2005-01-14
1304292863,1097073904,2016-01-01,4,RT,P,70623,NN,MINI,MINI,GREY,PE,1598,2004-04-08
845810407,1166548800,2016-01-01,4,NT,P,21567,DL,NISSAN,JUKE,BLUE,PE,1612,2011-07-07

I can see that the header row has 14 fields.
gawk -k '{print NF, $0}' hd.csv
14 test_id,vehicle_id,test_date,test_class_id,test_type,test_result,test_mileage,postcode_area,make,model,colour,fuel_type,cylinder_capacity,first_use_date
14 1645480751,1374211238,2016-01-01,4,NT,P,117033,SM,VOLKSWAGEN,POLO,BLACK,PE,1600,2000-06-23


I don't understand why the header row is getting skipped.

gid rid of the while read loop and use hd.csv as argument of gawk

Why do you have a shell while loop in that? It's not needed and is the cause

I thought I need to parse line by line when I was generating different output files.
@Fravadona you have made this so much simpler. Thanks.

You're reading the first line into the variable $line. Then gawk is reading the rest of standard input, so it processes the rest of the file.

Awk itself runs the defined rules line by line.

What's happening with your current design is that both the read and the awk are consuming from stdin, so it's only going through the loop once. The read is taking the header, and the loop then does nothing with it (you don't reference $line anywhere else.) Then awk is sucking up the rest of the file, and the next iteration of the loop hits EOF and exits.
$: printf "%s\n" 1 2 3 >f

$: cat f
1
2
3

$: cnt=0; while read line; do echo "loop $((++cnt)), read line:[$line]"; done < f
loop 1, read line:[1]
loop 2, read line:[2]
loop 3, read line:[3]

$: cnt=0; while read line; do echo "loop $((++cnt)), read line:[$line]"; awk '{print "awk line:["$1"]"}'; done < f
loop 1, read line:[1]
awk line:[2]
awk line:[3]

As stated already, just let awk read the file (as it's doing already anyway.)
Another take on it. :)
awk -F, '{f="good"} 14!=NF{f="bad";$0=NR" "NF" "$0} {print>f".csv"}' hd.csv

Every block gets executed on every line unless it hits a next or similar command, so set a default, then change things up on any records that need it.
My version doesn't have a -k, but -F, does basically the same thing.
Also, while it isn't hurting anything, you don't need that continuation.
awk -F, '{if(NF==14)print       $0 > "good.csv"; \
          else      print NR,NF,$0 > "bad.csv"   }' hd.csv

is functionally identical to
awk -F, '{if(NF==14)print       $0 > "good.csv"; # no backslash
          else      print NR,NF,$0 > "bad.csv"   }' hd.csv

awk doesn't mind a little whitespace in appropriate places
(and doesn't complain about comments, either.) :)

You don't need the while or the if
awk -F, 'NF==14 {print>"good.csv";next} {print "["NR"] ["NF"] " $0>"bad.csv"}' hd.csv


As others have pointed out, you shouldn't have a shell read loop involved. Specifically in your code, this:
while read -r line; 
do
   gawk -k '{if (NF==14) print $0 > "good_file.csv";     \
                         else print "["NR"]", "["NF"]", $0 > "bad_file.csv"}';
done < hd.csv

reads the first line of hd.csv into the shell variable line and then awk reads the rest of the input starting from line 2 still within that first (and last since awk won't stop reading lines until there's no input left) loop iteration.
You probably meant to write something like this where the shell reads each line and calls gawk 1 line at a time:
while IFS= read -r line; 
do
   printf '%s\n' "$line" | gawk -k '{if (NF==14) print $0 > "good_file.csv";     \
                         else print "["NR"]", "["NF"]", $0 > "bad_file.csv"}';
done < hd.csv

but that isn't necessary and would be immensely slow and fragile compared to just calling awk once, see why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice. You were also missing the IFS= off that while read construct.
You can do what you're trying to do in GNU awk (for -k aka --csv) with essentially what you had, just re-spaced here for clarity:
gawk -k -v OFS=',' '
    {
        if ( NF == 14 ) {
            print > "good_file.csv"
        }
        else {
            print "["NR"]", "["NF"]", $0 > "bad_file.csv"
        }
    }
' hd.csv

(note that I added -v OFS=',' so the additional output fields you're adding will also be comma instead of space separated since -k just specifies what separates the input, not the output) but I think you'll probably want both of your output files to have a header line and so one way to do that would be:
gawk -k -v OFS=',' '
    NR == 1 {
        print > "good_file.csv"
        print "NR", "NF", $0 > "bad_file.csv"
        next
    }
    NF == 14 {
        print > "good_file.csv"
        next
    }
    { print "["NR"]", "["NF"]", $0 > "bad_file.csv" }
' hd.csv

Note also that -k will strip any double quotes surrounding input fields so even with valid CSV input you could output invalid CSV if you don't handle adding quotes around fields and doubling any "s within the fields. See What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk? for how to handle that.
